# Why can't I sort by the primary key in CQL?

Tags: c#, cassandra

Why can I not order by the primary key?

```
CREATE TABLE "My_Data" (    
    "SeqNum" bigint,
    "ShoeSize" double ,   

    PRIMARY KEY ("SeqNum")    
)

select * "My_Data"
order by "SeqNum"
```

Error:

> ORDER BY is only supported when partition key is restricted by EQ or IN

Answer (score 6):

Because Cassandra only supports result set ordering *by* clustering keys, and *within* partitioning keys.  In your case, `"SeqNum"` is your partition key, and you do not have a clustering key defined.

I wrote an [article describing this functionality](https://www.datastax.com/blog/we-shall-have-order) last year.  Following my second example in the article, consider this table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE postsbyuser (
  userid bigint,
  posttime timestamp,
  postid uuid,
  postcontent text,
  PRIMARY KEY ((userid), posttime)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (posttime DESC);
```

If I were to INSERT six rows and then query the table:

```
> SELECT userid, token(userid), posttime FROM postsbyuser;
 
 userid | token(userid)        | posttime 
--------+----------------------+-------------------------- 
      1 | -4069959284402364209 | 2015-01-25 13:25:00-0600 
      1 | -4069959284402364209 | 2015-01-25 13:22:00-0600 
      0 | -3485513579396041028 | 2015-01-25 13:21:00-0600 
      2 | -3248873570005575792 | 2015-01-25 13:28:00-0600 
      2 | -3248873570005575792 | 2015-01-25 13:27:00-0600 
      2 | -3248873570005575792 | 2015-01-25 13:26:00-0600
```

A few things to note here:

1. `userid` is the partition key, and the rows are decidedly **not** in order by its values.
2. The values are actually "sorted" by the *hashed token value* for the partition key, as you can see from applying the `token` function to the `userid` column.
3. The table defines `posttime` as its clustering key, but the result set is not sorted by that column, either.  However, within each `userid`, the results *are* ordered by `posttime`.  This should tell you that you **cannot** sort query results in Cassandra on an unbound query (query without a `WHERE` clause).
4. To enforce a sorting order in the result set, you don't even need to use the `ORDER BY` clause.

If I want posts ordered by their post time, I will need to provide (in this case) an id for a specific user:

```
> SELECT userid, token(userid), posttime
FROM postsbyuser
WHERE userid=2;

 userid | token(userid)        | posttime 
--------+----------------------+-------------------------- 
      2 | -3248873570005575792 | 2015-01-25 13:28:00-0600 
      2 | -3248873570005575792 | 2015-01-25 13:27:00-0600 
      2 | -3248873570005575792 | 2015-01-25 13:26:00-0600
```

As you can see, the results for a query filtering by partition key *are* indeed in the descending order that is defined on the table definition.  Also, queries that return data from multiple partitions are non-performant, and considered to be an anti-pattern.